# Compare with two data sets in R programming

Tags: r, dataset

I have two files. One is from a money transferring system. The other one is system failed words.

How can I find all the records that contain messages with one of the "failed" words?

```
1, ATM, 2000, NY, PASS GENERATED 1000 500 100 100
2, ATM, 800, IL, GENERATED SYSTEM ERROR, 500 XXX
3, CRD,3200, TX, GENERATED SYSTEM PASS
4, WIR, 5000, NJ, GENERATED NETWORK FAILED IP 2093/9384
5, WIR, 3000, CA, GENERATED FATAL ERROR IP3094
6, WIR,4000, NC,GENERATED SUCESS IP093 8309
7, ATM ,1000, SC, SYSTEM PASS 837390 IP AB93
8, TRN, 800, IL, FAILED 9380 38383
9, TRN, 4500, GA, GENERATED PASS 980489
```

---

```
error.words
ERROR
FATAL
FAIL
FAILED
FAILURE
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? It's unclear how these data relate or exactly what type of statistical analysis you wish to perform. If you need statistical advice, try [stats.se] instead. If you have a specific programming question, edit your post to include the code you've tried so far and a description of exactly what went wrong. Also be sure to include your desired output.

Comment: I've posted masked data. We are trying to perform time series analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the expected result.  may be this helps:

```
  dat[grep(paste(error.words, collapse="|"), dat$V5),]
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = 1:9, V2 = c(" ATM", " ATM", " CRD", " WIR", 
" WIR", " WIR", " ATM ", " TRN", " TRN"), V3 = c(2000L, 800L, 
3200L, 5000L, 3000L, 4000L, 1000L, 800L, 4500L), V4 = c(" NY", 
" IL", " TX", " NJ", " CA", " NC", " SC", " IL", " GA"), V5 = c(" PASS GENERATED 1000  500 100 100", 
" GENERATED SYSTEM ERROR", " GENERATED SYSTEM PASS", " GENERATED NETWORK FAILED IP 2093/9384", 
" GENERATED FATAL ERROR IP3094", "GENERATED SUCESS IP093 8309", 
" SYSTEM PASS 837390 IP AB93", " FAILED 9380 38383", " GENERATED PASS 980489"
), V6 = c("", " 500 XXX", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

error.words <- c("ERROR", "FATAL", "FAIL", "FAILED", "FAILURE")
```